# numpy.unique generates a list unique in what regard?

Tags: python, numpy

If you input an array with general objects to `numpy.unique`, the result will be unique based upon what?

I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

class A(object): #probably exists a nice mixin for this :P
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a < other.a
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.a <= other.a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.a >= other.a
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.a > other.a
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.a != other.a
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A({})".format(self.a)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.__repr__()

np.unique(map(A, range(3)+range(3)))
```

which returns

```
array([A(0), A(0), A(1), A(1), A(2), A(2)], dtype=object)
```

but my intentions are to get:

```
array([A(0), A(1), A(2)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the duplicate `A(2)` is a typo, I think you simply need to define `__hash__` (see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)):

```
import numpy as np
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a < other.a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.a != other.a
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A({})".format(self.a)
    def __str__(self):
       return repr(self)
```

produces

```
>>> map(A, range(3)+range(3))
[A(0), A(1), A(2), A(0), A(1), A(2)]
>>> set(map(A, range(3)+range(3)))
set([A(0), A(1), A(2)])
>>> np.unique(map(A, range(3)+range(3)))
array([A(0), A(1), A(2)], dtype=object)
```

where I've used [`total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to reduce the proliferation of methods, as you guessed was possible. :^)

[Edited after posting to correct missing `__ne__`.]

Comment: adding __hash__ did it, so what is the formulae for a general object?
It checks the hash first and if the hash is the same it goes to __eq__ ?

Comment: I should have known this, it's too late I shouldn't be coding :P

Comment: If memory serves: first identity -- `x = float("nan"); len(set([x, x])) == 1`, even though `x != x` -- then it checks the hash, and if those don't match, then it knows the objects must not be equal; and if the hashes do match, it calls `__eq__`.  Compare `np.unique([np.nan, np.nan])` with `np.unique([np.nan, float("nan")])`, for example.