# numpy.unique acts weird with numpy.array of objects

Tags: python, numpy

This question is related to (but not the same as) "[numpy.unique generates a list unique in what regard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389605/numpy-unique-generates-a-list-unique-in-what-regard/16389667)"

The setup:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class UniqueObject(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a < other.a
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)
    def __str__(self):
        return "UniqueObject({})".format(self.a)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Expected behaviour of `np.unique`:

```
>>> np.unique([1, 1, 2, 2])
array([1, 2])
>>> np.unique(np.array([1, 1, 2, 2]))
array([1, 2])
>>> np.unique(map(UniqueObject, [1, 1, 2, 2]))
array([UniqueObject(1), UniqueObject(2)], dtype=object)
```

Which is no problem, it works. But this doesn't work as expected:

```
>>> np.unique(np.array(map(UniqueObject, [1, 1, 2, 2])))
array([UniqueObject(1), UniqueObject(1), UniqueObject(2), UniqueObject(2)], dtype=object)
```

How come np.array with dtype=object is handled differently than a python list with objects?

That is:

```
objs = map(UniqueObject, [1, 1, 2, 2])
np.unique(objs) != np.unique(np.array(objs)) #?
```

I'm running `numpy 1.8.0.dev-74b08b3` and `Python 2.7.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following through the source of `np.unique`, it seems that the branch which is actually taken is

```
else:
    ar.sort()
    flag = np.concatenate(([True], ar[1:] != ar[:-1]))
    return ar[flag]
```

which simply sorts the terms and then takes the ones which aren't equal to the previous one.  But shouldn't that work?.. oops.  This is on me.  Your original code defined `__ne__`, and I accidentally removed it when removing the comparisons being `total_ordering`-ed.

```
>>> UniqueObject(1) == UniqueObject(1)
True
>>> UniqueObject(1) != UniqueObject(1)
True
```

Putting `__ne__` back in:

```
>>> UniqueObject(1) != UniqueObject(1)
False
>>> np.array(map(UniqueObject, [1,1,2,2]))
array([UniqueObject(1), UniqueObject(1), UniqueObject(2), UniqueObject(2)], dtype=object)
>>> np.unique(np.array(map(UniqueObject, [1,1,2,2])))
array([UniqueObject(1), UniqueObject(2)], dtype=object)
```